# UIDatePicker white view in tableview cell

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode6

Added a UIDatePicker to a prototype cell and this is what is being displayed.
There are no other views present in that cell. Any thoughts?[image]

Answer (score -1):

With iOS7, Apple released the sample code `DateCell`

> Demonstrates formatted display of date objects in table cells and use of UIDatePicker to edit those values.
>
> As a delegate to this table, the sample uses the method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" to open the UIDatePicker control.
>
> For iOS 6.x and earlier, UIViewAnimation is used for sliding the UIDatePicker up on-screen and down off-screen. For iOS 7.x, the UIDatePicker is added in-line to the table view.
>
> The action method of the UIDatePicker will directly set the NSDate property of the custom table cell. In addition, this sample shows how to use NSDateFormatter class to achieve the custom cell's date-formatted appearance.

Documentation and sample code are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)